# How to resize image height and width in php codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, resize

```html
public function resize() {
  $config['width'] = $this->input->post('width');
  $config['height'] = $this->input->post('height');
  $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
  $config['source_image'] = './uploads1/book.jpg';
  $config['new_image'] = './uploads1/book_new.jpg';
  $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
  $resize = $this->image_lib->resize();
  
 }
```

How to resize image height and width  in php codeigniter, only height is not resizing properly but width i am getting

Comment: Are you getting an error?  You're not giving us much info to work with here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: Please add your code in your question itself. It would be helpful for anyone who comes and checks your question.

Comment: width is resizing but height is not resizing

Comment: @mehboob As you have mention `$config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;` it will mantain aspect ration of image. So it will automatically adjust height according to width. If you forcefully want to resize height and width both, then please try with `$config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE;`

Comment: I tried $config['maintain_ratio'] = FALSE but still also same error

Answer (score 0):

```
 $this->load->library('image_lib');
if (!empty($_FILES['advert_image'])) {

                $filename = substr(md5(time()), 0, 28) . strrchr($_FILES['advert_image']['name'], '.');
                $config['upload_path'] = 'public/events/images/';

                $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|jpeg|png|JPG|JPEG|PNG|BMP|bmp|gif|GIF';
                $config['file_name'] = $filename;

                $config['is_image'] = true;

                $this->load->library('upload', $config);
                $this->upload->initialize($config);
                //$this->upload->do_upload('advert_image');
                //start resize image
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('advert_image')) {
                    echo "error" . count;
                } else {
                    $image_data = $this->upload->data();

                    $configer = array(
                        'image_library' => 'gd2',
                        'source_image' => $image_data['full_path'],
                        'maintain_ratio' => TRUE,
                        'width' => 480,
                        'height' => 480,
                    );
                    $this->image_lib->clear();
                    $this->image_lib->initialize($configer);
                    $this->image_lib->resize();
                }
                //end resize 
                $profile_pic = isset($filename) ? $filename : "";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the library to use it after setting config values:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib', $config);
```

Be sure the input values of height is not empty too!